# Parse Push Notifications stop working after some time

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, push-notification, ionic-framework

I have set up parse push notifications on android and it works fine. However after some time, the device no longer receives the notifications. I have initialised the service in onCreate. Only if you open the app and register the device for push notifications again, will it start to receive alerts. Then, after a while it longer receives

Comment: Where are you adding Parse initialization? Activity `onCreate` or ?

Comment: @YuvaRaj Initialise in onCreate in the Application. Not the activity